# How can I determine if a string is within two strings if I don't know how it rolls over?

Tags: c#

It is easy to see that G is between A and Z, but if I have a user enter a range of serial numbers from `56AAA7105A25` to `56AAA71064D6`, how can I determine if another serial number or  range falls between the two serial numbers specified before.  In order for me to know if it falls between them, wouldn't I need to know how it rolls over.  The problem I am facing is that according to code (c# in this case), one value would be considered greater than and less than the two values I specified, but according to the user, the value they enter is actually outside the range.  How do I handle scenarios like this?

Comment: Perhaps you can show the code you are using to compare as well as the relevant values that are giving the wrong results. Its hard to see whether you are doing it right or wrong without seeing what you are doing. Can you see by eye that the value they have given is outside the range? Is it that you don't understand their criteria or just that the code is reachign the wrong conclusion?

Comment: @Chris, at the moment I don't have any code, however take the two values A1 and FF, 2 is less than both these values, but assume that when the user considers the single value 2B to be between A1 and FF.

Comment: In that case you should have a well specified ordering. ie an alogirthm that you can use to work out if A=B, A>B or A<B. If you don't have this algorithm then you can't solve the problem. If you do have the algorithm then we can help put it into good code. The example you give for example I would assume that the rightmost character is considered most significant which is why 2B is between A1 and FF. However, your client/user should be letting you know what expectation he has. Personally I'd say the user is wrong in your example if nothing has been specified otherwise. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your serial numbers can be ordered - you need to find out what algorithm the manufacturer uses.  The next thing to do is to use that algorithm to define an `IComparer<string>` that will compare two serial numbers to encapsulate that logic - you would have something like so:

```
public class SerialComparer : IComparer<T>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        // If x == y:
        //   return 0
        // If x > y:
        //   return 1
        // Else:
        //   return -1
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{

   var x = "56AAA7105A25"; 
   var y = "56AAA71064D6";
   var comparer = new SerialComparer();

   if (comparer.Compare(x, y) > 0)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("{0} is greater than {1}", x, y);
   }
   else
   {
       Console.WriteLine("{0} is not greater than {1}", x, y);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming those are hexadecimal numbers you should be able to convert them to a long(they're too big for a 32 bit int at 48 bits)

```
long.Parse("0x" + serialnumber);
```

Alternately, if you do know what the valid numbers are, and they aren't in a natural order, you can make a custom class, override the `<` and `>` operators, and throw an exception if a known invalid value is entered.

Comment: Is it possible your client is hashing something to come up with the serial number and has an unrealistic expectation that you can somehow order them by the original values without knowing what they are?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the algorithm for determining ordering then you need to find it. You can try to guess but this is going to probably lead to pain in the long run because the algorithm need not be simple.

Somebody must be able to tell you the answer to this? Your user sounds like they have some idea (enough to tell you you are wrong at least), whoever specced the code you are writing should do (if appropriate) or perhaps if the serial numbers are generated by another app you can find out from the developers of that app (or its documentation).

Once that algorithm is known it can be coded and then the next step is obviously pretty trivial. The key is trying to define the comparison which we can't help with because we don't know what it is either. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the serial numbers to an int and then check if one is between the others. If the serial numbers are just hex numbers, this is not at all difficult, if they consist of the entire alphabet, you just have to build a function that converts the number with a given base (0-9 + A-Z would be 25, I guess) to an int. Just see A-Z as digits with value 10-25.

Comment: Correct me if am wrong, but even if I convert it to an int, one serial number according to the manufacturer should be considered outside the range, but according to the code, it would fall between the range, so converting it to an int would not solve the problem.

Comment: It is also known as a radix... 0-9 is radix 10,  0-F is 16 and 0-z would be 36. Also I think the above answer should be using 35 instead of 25.

Comment: I don't understand you in detail, but do you actually understandthe difference between string comparision and number/int comparision?

Comment: sry @GeorgeBailey, miscalculated with 9+25 :P

Comment: The serials in the question exceed the int type at large and I doubt they will even fit into long.

Comment: Let me clarify, what if the serial number that gets converted to an int is between two serial numbers, but because of the way the manufacturer rolls their serial numbers, although the int is between them, they view that as actually being outside the range, so although, B3 is between A1 and CF if we convert it to an int, what if the manufacturer serial number B3 is considered outside the range of A1 and CF although from a code perspective, it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You need to know how the serial numbers are defined.  If you don't know yourself how two serial numbers compare then your code won't be able to get it right either.

Comment: This is the problem I am facing.

Comment: Where do the serial numbers come from?  If understanding the relative order is important to your business, can't you just ask the creator?

Answer (score 0):

Just go through the number from left to right (don't forget to pad all numbers with zeros to the same length), and compare the two digits/letters on this position. If they differ, you can break the loop.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SerialNumber first = new SerialNumber("56AAA7105A25");
            SerialNumber second = new SerialNumber("57AAA71064C6");
            SerialNumber third = new SerialNumber("58AAA71064D6");

            Console.WriteLine(first.CompareTo(second));
            Console.WriteLine(second.CompareTo(third));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    struct SerialNumber : IComparable<SerialNumber>
    {
        public string Serial { get; set; }


        public SerialNumber(string serial) : this()
        {
            this.Serial = serial;
        }

        public int CompareTo(SerialNumber other)
        {
            int compareTo = 0;

            using (CharEnumerator enum1 = Serial.GetEnumerator())
            using (CharEnumerator enum2 = other.Serial.GetEnumerator())
            {
                while (enum1.MoveNext() && enum2.MoveNext())
                {
                    if (enum1.Current != enum2.Current)
                    {
                        compareTo = enum1.Current.CompareTo(enum2.Current);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return compareTo;
        }
    }
```